# Python range with variables

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7, range

I have write code as below:

```
start = 96
range = 5
for d in range(start, start+range):
    print d
```

---

but I get exception as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

---

Does Python not support multiple variable in range function?

Comment: `range = 5`, use a different variable name on this line

Comment: Why is this getting downvoted? It's an easy mistake to make and a difficult mistake to google...

Answer (score 4):

You overwrote `range`.

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> range = 2
>>> range(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Shadowing(overwriting) builtin function is not a good practice.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in this line

```
range = 5
```

You assign over the builtin function thus its the same as doing

```
a = 5
a()
```

Which isn't allowed. Try

```
range_ = 5
range(start, start+range_)
```

Answer (score 1):

`range` can, as any identifier, represent either a number or a function (or other things) but not both at the same time. Use another variable name